# How to resolve ParseError in odoo 8?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

When i customized res.users tree view its working fine.

```
<record model='ir.ui.view' id='transtech_usr'>

        <field name='name'>Base Res users</field>
        <field name="model">res.users</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='login_date']" position='attributes'>
                <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//tree//field[@name='lang']" position="after">
                <field name='role'/>
                <field name='contact_num' />
                <field name='joining_date' />
            </xpath>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

But the problem arises When it comes to edit form view...

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `sel_groups_7` does not exist

Error context:
View `users form`
[view_id: 320, xml_id: n/a, model: res.users, parent_id: 153]" while parsing /home/surya/Desktop/odoo-8.0/openerp/addons/ctran/view.xml:1497,    near 
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="transtech_user_form">
        <field name="name">users form</field>
        <field name="model">res.users</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

              <xpath expr="//field[@name='active']" position="after">
                  <group>
                      <field name="survey_limit"/>
                  </group>    

              </xpath>

            </field>
    </record>
```

When i want to insert some fields in users form , i am getting above error. I think as this form itself having inherited views i'm above error. but i dont know to resolve it. Plz help me.

Thanks, chandu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally got a solution thank you all for helping me out..

```
<record model='ir.ui.view' id='transtech_user_form'>
        <field name='name'>users form</field>
        <field name="model">res.users</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
                <field name="active" position="after">
                    <field name='survey_limit'/>
                </field>

        </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

And also add 'share' module as depends in **openerp**.py

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't go through your code but it seems you facing the traceback regarding `Field sel_groups_7 does not exist`. For that, the solution is you need to add `'share'` module in `depends` in `__openerp__.py`. For your ref you can see [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/6324)

Comment: Hi, now its now showing any error but .. the fields were not showing in form view... its not working,.. what to do??

Comment: Nope.. See my answer..!! Thank you

Comment: you should put this answer as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to encapsulate the 2 **xpath** into a single **data** tag:

```
    <field name='name'>Base Res users</field>
    <field name="model">res.users</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='login_date']" position='attributes'>
                <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//tree//field[@name='lang']" position="after">
                <field name='role'/>
                <field name='contact_num' />
                <field name='joining_date' />
            </xpath>
        </data>
    </field>
</record>
```

about the form view, I suppose the error is due to inheritance chain of **view_users_tree** view.
Maybe you should check whether you previously removed some module.
The field in error is an automatic generated field, then is not easy to find... Try grep on your code for *sel_groups*

Comment: Hey, Its not working .. actually i didnt get you ??!! exactly what do you wanna say.. can you please explain it ...Thanks

Comment: see my edit: did you try it this way and it still doesn't work?

Comment: in tree view its working fine sir, i have got problem at form view... see the error code. that is for res.users form view.. plz help me. thank you

Comment: Sure sir, i am working on it.. hope it will be resolved with in hours.. the problem is base.view_users_form inherited 3 or 4 views so i have to locate the fields and then it would work. Thank you